# Loop through files using pdf-table-extractor package

Tags: json, node.js

I have a list of pdf files and I want to extract tables from these files.
So I use [pdf-table-extractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-table-extractor) to to this.

If I had only one pdf file, I can use this code:

```
var url = {title: 'Italy-2016-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2016-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_5_file.pdf'};

function pdfToJson() {
    var inputFile = './output/ita/' + url.filename;
    pdf_table_extractor(inputFile, success, error);
} 

function success(result) {
    var out = './output/ita' + url.filename;
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(out);
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
        stream.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        stream.end();
    });
} 

function error(err) {
    console.error('Error: ' + err);
}
```

But I have 17 pdf files, so I had to loop through these file.
The problem is define the output filename inside `success()` function.
This is my code:

```
var urls = [
    {title: 'Italy-2016-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2016-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_5_file.pdf'},
    {title: 'Italy-2015-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2015-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_3_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2014-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2014-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_2_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2013-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2013-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_1_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2012-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2012-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_5_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2011-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2011-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_6_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2010-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2010-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_7_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2009-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2009-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_8_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2008-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2008-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_15_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2007-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2007-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_14_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2006-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2006-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_13_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2005-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2005-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_12_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2004-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2004-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_11_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2003-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2003-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_10_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2002-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2002-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_9_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2001-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2001-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_1_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {title: 'Italy-2000-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2000-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}
];

function pdfToJson() {
    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        var inputFile = './output/ita/' + url.filename;
        pdf_table_extractor(inputFile, success, error);
    });
}

function success(result) {
    var out = './output/ita' + ???; // <-- PROBLEM HERE
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(out);
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
        stream.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        stream.end();
    });
} 

function error(err) {
    console.error('Error: ' + err);
}
```

To write the structure of this code I followed the example found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-table-extractor), although I don't really like how the code is organized.

Would anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope below answer will solve your problem.

```
var urls = [
{title: 'Italy-2016-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2016-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_5_file.pdf'},
{title: 'Italy-2015-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2015-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_3_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2014-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2014-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_2_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2013-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2013-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_1_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2012-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2012-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_5_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2011-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2011-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_6_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2010-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2010-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_7_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2009-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2009-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_8_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2008-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2008-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_15_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2007-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2007-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_14_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2006-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2006-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_13_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2005-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2005-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_12_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2004-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2004-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_11_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2003-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2003-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_10_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2002-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2002-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_9_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2001-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2001-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_1_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
{title: 'Italy-2000-Vaccine coverage 24 months', filename: 'ita-2000-24m.pdf', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}];

function pdfToJson() {
  urls.forEach(function(url) {
    var inputFile = './output/ita/' + url.filename;
    pdf_table_extractor(inputFile, function(result){

      success(url,result);

    }, function(error){

      error(url,error);

    });
  });
}

/*function pdfToJson() {
   urls.forEach(function(url) {
      var inputFile = './output/ita/' + url.filename;
      pdf_table_extractor(inputFile, success, error);
   });
}*/

function success(url,result) {
   var out = './output/ita' + url.filename; // <-- PROBLEM HERE
   var stream = fs.createWriteStream(out);
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
      stream.write(JSON.stringify(result));
      stream.end();
    });
 } 

 function error(url,err) {
  console.error('Error: ' + err);
 }
```

Comment: Hi,  I am trying the same thing...but instead of writing a stream, Im trying to put it into another variable.  How do i do that?  When i try to run the program the variable output is coming up undefined.